# Need to change a mouse event args with a checkbox

Tags: vb.net, class, checkbox, mouseevent

I have a class that changes the mouse event args of a picturebox and allows the user to resize it during runtime.  I am trying to add a checkbox for each picturebox that will maintain the aspect ratio of the picturebox when the checkbox is checked.

I can get it to work if I add the code separately for each checkbox on the form but I want to keep it in a separate class so that it works for any checkbox.

Here is the code for the class to resize the pictureboxes

```
Public Class ResizeableControl
Public WithEvents mControl As Control

Public mPreserveAspectRatio As Boolean

Dim AtRightEdge As Boolean = False
Dim AtBottomEdge As Boolean = False
Dim InBoxWidth As Boolean = False
Dim InBoxHeight As Boolean = False
Dim DraggingHorizontal As Boolean
Dim DraggingVerticle As Boolean
Dim DraggingCorner As Boolean
Const DragMarginWidth As Integer = 6
Const DragMarginHeight As Integer = 6
Public dragOrigin As Point
Dim MoveBox As Boolean = False
Dim LastPos As Point


Public Sub New(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal preserveAspectRatio As Boolean)
    mControl = Control
    mPreserveAspectRatio = preserveAspectRatio
End Sub


Private Sub mControl_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles mControl.MouseMove

    If MoveBox Then
        Dim movement As Point = Cursor.Position
        ' move image by the distance the mouse moved hoizontally and vertically
        movement.Offset(-LastPos.X, -LastPos.Y)
        mControl.Location = movement
    ElseIf DraggingHorizontal Then
        Dim movement As Point = New Point(e.X - dragOrigin.X, e.Y - dragOrigin.Y)  'How far did the mouse move? (Distance = newPoint - oldPoint)

        If mPreserveAspectRatio = True Then
            mControl.Width += movement.X 'Change width of the image by the distance the mouse moved
            mControl.Height = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(mControl.Width) / 6.0) * 4.0)
        Else
            mControl.Width += movement.X 'Change width of the image by the distance the mouse moved
        End If

        dragOrigin = e.Location 'Next time we will measure from the now-current mouse position
    ElseIf DraggingVerticle Then
        Dim movement As Point = New Point(e.X - dragOrigin.X, e.Y - dragOrigin.Y)

        If mPreserveAspectRatio = True Then
            mControl.Height += movement.Y 'Change height of the image by the distance the mouse moved
            mControl.Width = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(mControl.Height) / 4.0) * 6.0)
        Else
            mControl.Height += movement.Y 'Change height of the image by the distance the mouse moved
        End If

        dragOrigin = e.Location
    ElseIf DraggingCorner Then
        Dim movement As Point = New Point(e.X - dragOrigin.X, e.Y - dragOrigin.Y)

        If mPreserveAspectRatio = True Then
            ' Resize the image by the distance the mouse moved hoizontally and vertically
            mControl.Height += movement.Y
            mControl.Width += movement.X
            mControl.Height = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(mControl.Width) / 6.0) * 4.0)
            mControl.Width = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(mControl.Height) / 4.0) * 6.0)
        Else
            ' Resize the image by the distance the mouse moved hoizontally and vertically
            mControl.Height += movement.Y
            mControl.Width += movement.X
        End If

        dragOrigin = e.Location
    Else
        ' Is mouse within right six-or-so pixels?
        AtRightEdge = e.X > (mControl.Width - DragMarginWidth)
        ' Is mouse within bottom six-or-so pixels?
        AtBottomEdge = e.Y > (mControl.Height - DragMarginHeight)
        ' Is mouse within the box?
        InBoxWidth = e.X < (mControl.Width - DragMarginWidth)
        InBoxHeight = e.Y < (mControl.Height - DragMarginHeight)


        ' Set the cursor accordingly
        If (AtBottomEdge And AtRightEdge) Then
            mControl.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE
        ElseIf (InBoxWidth And InBoxHeight) Then
            mControl.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll
        ElseIf (AtBottomEdge) Then
            mControl.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS
        ElseIf (AtRightEdge) Then
            mControl.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE
        Else
            mControl.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub mControl_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles mControl.MouseDown

    ' If the user presses the mouse button at the bottom right corner, begin dragging
    If (InBoxWidth And InBoxHeight) Then

        Dim movement As Point = Cursor.Position
        movement.Offset(-mControl.Location.X, -mControl.Location.Y)
        LastPos = movement
        MoveBox = True
    ElseIf (AtBottomEdge And AtRightEdge) Then
        dragOrigin = e.Location
        DraggingCorner = True
    ElseIf AtRightEdge Then
        dragOrigin = e.Location
        DraggingHorizontal = True
    ElseIf AtBottomEdge Then
        dragOrigin = e.Location
        DraggingVerticle = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub mControl_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles mControl.MouseUp
    ' Stop dragging
    MoveBox = False
    DraggingHorizontal = False
    DraggingVerticle = False
    DraggingCorner = False
End Sub

Private Sub mControl_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mControl.MouseLeave
    MoveBox = False
    DraggingHorizontal = False
    DraggingVerticle = False
    DraggingCorner = False
    mControl.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
 End Class
```

I create a new instance of the class for each picturebox (I have just 2 here to keep it simple but have more) when the form loads but then I can't figure out how to change the aspect ratio boolean (mPreserveAspectRatio).  I have tried just changing the boolean when the checkbox changes states but that doesn't work.  And I think I may need to somehow create a public method to change the boolean but can't wrap my head around it. Here is the latest code I have been trying that doesn't work

```
    Imports WindowsApplication1.ResizeableControl

    Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mControl As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox1, True)
    Dim mControl2 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox2, True)

     End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Dim mControl1 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox1, True)
    Else
        Dim mControl1 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox1, False)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged

    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        Dim mControl1 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox2, True)
    Else
        Dim mControl1 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox2, False)
    End If

End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: In your second code sample, you have all these `Dim mControl1 = ...` lines... `Dim` creates a variable that's local in scope. You're creating that control, but throwing it away as soon as you're done executing that event-handler. You probably need to do something like `Me.Controls.Add(mControl1)` so it is actually added to the form.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I tried what you suggested and got the following error  Value of type 'WindowsApplication1.ResizeableControl' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.  The control actually works when I execute it this way.  I am just not able to change the control once I do

Comment: Sorry what I mean is when I use **Dim mControl As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox1, True)** The control works but **Dim mControl As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox1, False)** doesn't change the aspect ratio setting Using Me.Controls.Add(mControl1) gives the error above.

Comment: You might see if you can narrow down the problem a bit... a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) is more likely to find an answer here. You can edit your question with just the information we need to reproduce/solve the problem once you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You pointed me in the right direction Jeff.  I did need to add the control to the form.  Here is what I did.

```
Imports WindowsApplication1.ResizeableControl

Public Class Form1

Dim mControl1 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox1, True)
Dim mControl2 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox2, True)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Control1 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox1, True)
    Me.mControl1 = Control1
    Dim Control2 As New ResizeableControl(PictureBox2, True)
    Me.mControl2 = Control2

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Me.mControl1.mPreserveAspectRatio = True
    Else
        Me.mControl1.mPreserveAspectRatio = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        Me.mControl2.mPreserveAspectRatio = True
    Else
        Me.mControl2.mPreserveAspectRatio = False
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```